# Configuring Ninject in App_start folder specifically ninjectwebcommon.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple query, i am following the tutorial on this link:
http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1#book-unique-identifier
My problem is the author on this tutorial configure ninject in the global.asax file and deleted the ninjectwebcommon.cs file. i am trying to integrate the justblog into my existing asp.netMVC5 application that is using the ninjectwebcommon.cs file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's the exact issue you are facing? can u elaborate

Comment: @qamar am following this http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1#book-unique-identifier

Comment: you can just create an instance of ninjectwebcommon class in your global.asax app_start function. it will be instantiated when the application starts

Comment: @qamar am sorry to ask this but i how??? could you point me in the right direction cause i am very new to asp.netmvc5

Comment: please find global.asax.cs file and look for a method named as Application_OnStart . Inside that method create a new ninjectwebcommon()

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Nuget to add Ninject? You'll need a reference to `WebActivatorEx` for the bootstrapper to work (obviously along with the other required Ninject references). Add a NinjectWebCommon.cs class in your `App_Start` folder in your project, looking like this:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(YourMvcApp.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(YourMvcApp.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace YourMvcApp.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(); // you'll add modules to the parameter list here
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                //RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        ///// <summary>
        ///// Load your modules or register your services here!
        ///// </summary>
        ///// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        //private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        //{
        //}
    }
}
```